# ASP MVC Code First Table Creation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a table in my  EF model that is not creating within the database on access.

The table name is "sites" and is linked to a parent table by the use of a foreign key called "CompanyId".

I am attmempting to list all the sites that belong to a specific company (the company table is linked to the ApplicationUser)

I would expect that when i call the database for a list of the sites that it will be created. However i just receive an error that states the table does not exist

My model for the two tables is as follow

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual IQueryable<Site> Sites { get; set; }


}



public class Site
{
    [Key]
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }


}
```

and my controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        //get the user details
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var currentuser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        // search 
        var company = currentuser.Companies;
        var sites = company.Sites;

        if (sites == null)
        {

           sites = db.Sites.Where(c => c.CompanyId == company.CompanyId);



            return View(sites.ToList());
        }

        return View(company.Sites.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Did you add a `DbSet` for that table in the context?

Comment: yes i added the DbSet within the DbContext Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can see which table is created in your database using Database Manager?**

Try

1: Change

```
public virtual IQueryable<Site> Sites { get; set; }
```

for

```
public virtual ICollection<Site> Sites { get; set; }
```

2: Add property to your site class

```
public Company Company { get; set; }
```

Comment: this turned out to enable the table to be created, the new still wont load but ill create another question for this. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a migration for the change? If not the issue the "Add-Migration whateverYouWant" command in your package manager console.

Do you have automatic migrations enabled? If not then you have to auth the command "update-database" in your package manager console.

Look into your Configuration.cs file under the Migrations folder
and check the Configuration constructor. There should be a property called "AutomaticMigrationsEnabled" set to true in order for this to do what you are expecting.

Comment: I had enable migrations but not the automatic flag was set to false. I have just tried "add-migration" (which generated a blank migration file) and then "update-database" however there was no change

Comment: i have even tried deleting the database but that didnt work